# AWS Lambda - NodeJS CSV Data to S3 File

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Experts,

I have a JSON object that I need to save to the S3 bucket as a CSV file. This is what I have managed so far but unfortunately, the file is not getting created on S3 and no error is reported.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const converter = require('json-2-csv');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: "Key",
    secretAccessKey: "Secret"
});

exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const s3Bucket = "bucketname";
    const objectName = event.operation + new Date().getTime() + "_" + event.userId + ".";
    const objectData = (event.rawData);
    const objectType = "text/csv";

    converter.json2csv(objectData, async(err, csv) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(" Error ", err)
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(csv);
        try {
            const params = {
                Bucket: s3Bucket,
                Key: objectName,
                Body: (csv),
                ContentType: objectType,
                ContentDisposition: 'attachment',
            };
            console.log('Writing to s3 bucket..');
            const result = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
            console.log('Finished Writing to s3 bucket..', objectName);
            return sendRes(200, `File uploaded successfully at https:/` + s3Bucket + `.s3.amazonaws.com/` + objectName);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return sendRes(404, error);
        }
    });
};
const sendRes = (status, body) => {
    var response = {
        statusCode: status,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "X-Requested-With": "*"
        },
        body: body
    };
    return response;
};
```

If I remove the JSON to CSV converter and try saving the JSON data as a JSON file then it works with a charm - by changing the objectType to "application/json".

What am I doing wrong here when converting to CSV ?

P.S: JSON to CSV conversion works fine and this is the last printed log.

> Writing to s3 bucket..

Comment: There is no issue in code, I did POC with your code by just removing 'context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;' and the csv file is stored in my bucket. There might be something problem in your bucket

Comment: well I am able to write to the same bucket as a JSON file - just by changing the contentType

Comment: is there an aswer for this? :/

Comment: there was a problem with the library "json-2-csv". i used another one and its working for us